# how to get element inner <iframe> of <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html

i have simple webpage and in this webpage ,  tage and thats id "a1" , this  contain inner one more  tag, and thats id "a2". i want to get element  tag that's id="a2" by using javascript .

**please helpe me, how can i get `<h1>` tag using javascript :**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>get element from inner iframe </title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>hello world</h1>
  
<iframe id="a1" >
  
    <iframe id="a2">
        <h1 id="b1">help me</h1>
        <p  id="b2" >for get HTML tag using javascript DOM</p>
    </iframe>
  
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use document.getElementById("a2");

Comment: $( document.getElementById("a2").contentWindow.document.body ).children()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't put HTML code directly inside an iframe.
You have to separate it into a different file, and then link it by adding a "src" attribute to the iframe.

Now, assuming you have 3 file:

1. index.html - that contains the reference first iframe (#a1) and points to iframe1.html
2. iframe1.html - that contains the reference to the second iframe (#a2) and points to iframe2.html
3. iframe2.html - that contains the desired h1 tag (#b1)

Here is the code you need to get to it:

```
var iframe1 = document.getElementById('a1');
var iframeDoc1 = iframe1.contentDocument || iframe1.contentWindow.document;

var iframe2 = iframeDoc1.getElementById('a2');
var iframeDoc2 = iframe2.contentDocument || iframe2.contentWindow.document;

var innerH1 = iframeDoc2.getElementById('b1');
```

Basically, you get each iframe, then you get its inner document, and then you look inside it.

Comment: actually , my iframe's content is come from other domain, so this code work in my script ???

Answer (score 0):

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document. Its better to user any other tag in place of `iframe`. As in your code `h1` tag has and id attribute. You can get `h1` tag by its id attribute.

```
var x= document.getElementById("b1");

alert(x.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');// your frame id here
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Or you can use

```
window.frames['frameID'].document.getElementById('frameID')
```